# Cassandra composite column and pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I have a column family with either string values or a composite type value.

How can I load this kind of data from cassandra to pig?

Answer (score 0):

Our Pig loadfunc does not support composite columns yet.  You can watch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3684 for progress.